# Return items from list in function. Python

Tags: python, list, function, return

```
my_list = ['a','b','c']

def func(input):
    for i in input:
        print i
print func(my_list)
```

Output

```
a
b
c
None
```

I don't want the 'None' so **how I can do a single line of code to return the items in my input list?**

I tried:

```
return for i in input: print i
```

but it didn't work because return statements don't work like that

Comment: I don't even know what I was trying to ask looking back at this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are printing the return code from `func` which is `none`. Just call `func(my_list)` without the `print`.

Answer (score 2):

Functions, by default, return `None` if they come to the end of themselves without returning.  So, since there are no `return` statements in `func`, it will return `None` when called.

Furthermore, by using `print func(my_list)`, you are telling Python to print what is returned by `func`, which is `None`.

To fix your problem, just drop the `print` and do:

```
func(my_list)
```

Also, if `my_list` isn't very long, then you don't really need a function at all to do what you are doing.  Just use the `join` method of a string like so:

```
>>> my_list = ['a','b','c']
>>> print "\n".join(my_list)
a
b
c
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `print func(my_list)` - just do:

```
func(my_list)
```